# How can I convert List of Maps into List of Map in dart

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I want to convert List of Maps into List of Map in dart. I want it Like this

```
{'frequency[]':Monday,'frequency[]':Tuesday,'frequency[]':Friday,'frequency[]':Saturday,}
```

This is the List Data I am Getting:

```
{frequency[]: Monday}, {frequency[]: Tuesday}, {frequency[]: Friday}, {frequency[]: Saturday}
```

This What I am doing so Far..

```
List list = [];

         for (var i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
           var result = {for (var v in frequency) 'frequency[]': frequency[i]};

           list.add(result);

           // list.add('frequency[]':)
         }
         //{'frequency[]':Monday,'frequency[]':Tuesday,'frequency[]':Friday,'frequency[]':Saturday,}

         print('This is the List Passed to the Api ${list.map((e) => e)}');
       }
```

Comment: your expected output doesn't make sense map don't allow duplicate keys

Comment: Yes, You are ri8. but in my case, I have to pass the array of JSON to form data. That way, I need to pass these key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using

```
for (var i in frequency.entries.toList()) {
    list.add({i.key: i.value});
}
```

This iterates through the MapEntries in the map and makes a new map for each entry.